# Java Daytime Client

Tags: java

I need to get current time from a date time server by using following code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*; 

class DaytimeClient {
      public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        if ((args.length != 1))
        ("Syntax: DaytimeClient <host>[:<port>]");

        int idx = args[0].indexOf (":");
        int port = (idx > -1) ? Integer.parseInt (args[0].substring (idx + 1))
          : 13;
        String hostName = (idx > -1) ? args[0].substring (0, idx) : args[0];
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName (hostName);

        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket ();
        socket.setSoTimeout (5000);
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket (new byte[256], 1, host, port);
        socket.send (packet);
        packet.setLength (packet.getData ().length);
        socket.receive (packet);
        socket.close ();

        byte[] data = packet.getData ();
        int length = packet.getLength ();
        System.out.println (new String (data, 0, length, "latin1"));
    }
}
```

after compile i run this code with "java DaytimeClient 165.193.126.229".But it doesn't worked.
Got the error

> C:\daytimeclient>java DaytimeClient 96.47.67.105
>   Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketReceiveOrPeekData(Native Method)
>           at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(Unknown Source)
>           at DaytimeClient.main(DaytimeClient.java:32)

Then i wrote a server as follow,

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class DaytimeServer {
  public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 13;
  public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    if (args.length > 1)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Syntax: DaytimeServer [<port>]");
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket
      (args.length == 0 ? DEFAULT_PORT : Integer.parseInt (args[0]));
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket (new byte[1], 1);
    while (true) {
      socket.receive (packet);
      System.out.println
        ("Received from: " + packet.getAddress () + ":" + packet.getPort ());
      byte[] outBuffer = new java.util.Date ().toString ()
        .getBytes ("latin1");
      packet.setData (outBuffer);
      packet.setLength (outBuffer.length);
      socket.send (packet);
    }
  }
}
```

And run the first code with "java DaytimeClient localhost". Then it's work.

I need to do my work with a remort day time server so why "java DaytimeClient 165.193.126.229" doesn't worked.

(Reference codes got from http://www.stepwise.hk/npwiki/Tutorial/JavaUDPDaytime)

Comment: Is the remote system even running a daytime service?

Comment: I got the server informations from here, http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi

Comment: Have you tried connecting to it by other means? Are you sure there's no firewall in the way blocking it?

Comment: I again repeat the question, bearing in mind that on that page they mention that `We expect to replace the tcp version of this protocol with a udp-based version near the end of 2013`. I would expect that they would mention if the UDP protocol is now implemented.

Comment: did you start your server for sure? Did you tried on different port? Maybe some fancy firewall rules are blocking communications (yes, it is possible to block loop connections from/to localhost)